Simpler UserFrosting alternatives?
I am looking for a lightweight PHP&MySQL user management system which can provide a login/signup screen for guests and user profile for logged-in users, a few access levels (so I can decide what to display to them), and a google oauth option as well...
I saw that there is this "UserFrosting" framework but I cannot fathom how to even start the installation process and besides, it's requirements are ridiculous and it seems like an overkill. I just want to copy the PHP files to my server and visit the "install.php", is there such software?

Hello, WDYM by "cannot fathom how to even start"? Did you follow the documentation? https://learn.userfrosting.com/#installing-userfrosting It looks straightforward to me. Is it because of missing composer on your shared hosting or something alike? But then you mentioned a "server"

Hi Destroy666! Yes it is a free shared hosting, and I really don't quite get it how it is installed, I know how to copy some php files and maybe import a database or similar stuff but I cannot think beyond that :)

Well, installing Composer is also quite easy if you follow any guidance. But it might not be an option on many shared hostings. You can always use Composer locally and copy the files, though. Or ask the hosting to help you install Composer.

As for software, you might have tough time finding anything more Wordpress-like, as almost anything modern uses Composer.

I actually don't need any fancy stuff like Wordpress, just a library which would handle login/sign up, user id's, user categories (ie. access levels), and that is pretty much it

I mean Wordpress-like in terms of installation.
